# calling factory function in service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call factory function in service.

My factory looks like this:

```
 function LMSAppFactory($http) {
        var ajaxRequest = 'processRequest.jsp?';

       return {    
            getTableData: getTableData,
       }; 

       function getTableData(params, callback) {
           alert(1);
            $http.get(ajaxRequest + 'requestType=getRecords'+params+'&value=10').then(function (response) {
                callback(response.data[1].LMSRecords, response.data[0].LMSRecordsCount);
            });
        }

    }
```

My service

```
$scope.branchSearch = function (code){
    alert(code);
    getData: LMSAppFactory.getTableData;
}
```

I am getting value in `branchSearch` function but not call in factory function.

Please suggest where is my mistake?

Comment: What is this syntax `getData: LMSAppFactory.getTableData`? This wont call the factory function. Instead, you should call it directly like `LMSAppFactory.getTableData(code)`.

Comment: Just an FYI really but why are you still following the callback way of working? Promise based workflows are far superior (A quick Google search will give you info on that). Simply return the `$http.get` call to return the promise out of your service. Either way your not handling any errors your network request may throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code is incomplete but i don't get what you're trying to do in the below code (invocation? assignment? are you trying to define a [label statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) but why?)

```
$scope.branchSearch = function (code){
   alert(code);
   getData: LMSAppFactory.getTableData; // <-- HERE
}
```

if you want to invoke getTableData a valid invocation could be

```
$scope.branchSearch = function (code){
        alert(code);
        var params = {} //pass the parameters here
        LMSAppFactory.getTableData(params, function(val1, val2){
          //callback behaviour here
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You factory declaration seems to be right, but there is a problem with its call., here `getData: LMSAppFactory.getTableData;`, you not calling the factory.

Also, you need to inject `LMSAppFactory` factory inside your service if not already. Like :

```
angular.module('yourmodule')
    .service('yourBranchService', ['LMSAppFactory', function(LMSAppFactory) {
           //service code
      }
]);
```

Then, finally in service, make call to factory method :

```
$scope.branchSearch = function (code){
        alert(code);
        var inputParams = {}; // fill params
        LMSAppFactory.getTableData(inputParams, callback)
 }

function callback(lmsRecords, lmsCount){
    // call back implementaion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not invoking you factory function only aasigning it's reference to the controller.

If you want the `$scope.branchSearch` method to get the data from the factory you should it like this:

```
$scope.branchSearch = function (code){
    $scope.data = LMSAppFactory.getTableData(params, code); // <= i assume -code- is your calllback
}
```

This way you invoke the function and send it the `code` parameter you fgot from the caller function